# How to set products in multiple websites using magmi?

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I have all my products in "main" website. I have another website and code is "new". I want to add all my products in "new" website too. But when i try to do so, products remove from "main" website and add in "new" website. I want my products in both websites. How to achieve that task?
my csv is..

> sku websites
>
> 123 new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect csv format is

> sku websites
>
> 123 main,new

By using this, product would be imported in both websites "main" and "new".

Comment: is possible can you give csv demo.

Comment: How can i import images using by magmi for my multi store Magento? As a single store its working fine, after added additional store, magmi image not working.  csv screen shot : https://snag.gy/Ju6MbK.jpg if i did any error, pls let me know and demo CSV sheet.